# Cómo continuar un envío de correos masivos si se encuentra una excepción

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, excepciones

¿Cómo podría hacer para que cuando se encuentre una excepción al enviar correos masivos no se detenga y siga con el envío de correos?

Código de ejecución:

```
public String EnviarEmail() {
    vect = getTo().split(";");
    vectCodigo = getCodigo().split(";");
    vectNombre = getNombre().split(";");

    Properties props = null;
    Session session = null;
    MimeMessage message = null;
    Address fromAddress = null;
    Address toAddress = null;
    MimeMultipart multiParte = null;

    props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", getSmtp());
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", getPort());

    session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(getUsername(), getPassword());
        }
    });

    message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < vect.length; i++) {
            //BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Leer la plantilla
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "/net/feban/envioEmail/Imagen_PlantillaMensaje");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            // Almacenar el contenido de la plantilla en un StringBuffer
            String strLine;
            StringBuffer msjHTML = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    msjHTML.append(strLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Parametros
//              String nombreAfiliado = "Bruno Torres Torres";
//              String codAfiliado = "00005";
//              String c_t_email = "ltorrestorres@hotmail.com";
            String mensajeEnviar = msjHTML.toString();
            mensajeEnviar = mensajeEnviar.replace("$$codAfiliado", vectCodigo[i]);
            mensajeEnviar = mensajeEnviar.replace("$$Afiliado", vectNombre[i]);
            mensajeEnviar = mensajeEnviar.replace("$$email", vect[i]);

            // Creo la parte del mensaje HTML
            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            mimeBodyPart.setContent(mensajeEnviar, "text/html");

            multiParte = new MimeMultipart();
            multiParte.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(multiParte);
            fromAddress = new InternetAddress(getFrom());//quien lo envia (from)
            message.setFrom(fromAddress);
            toAddress = new InternetAddress(vect[i]);//para quien se envia
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
            message.saveChanges();

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(getSmtp(), getPort(), getUsername(), getPassword());
            if (!transport.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Error de envio\n");
            }
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("Enviando Correos\n");
            System.out.println("Enviado a: " + vect[i] + "\n");
            System.out.println("Enviado a: " + vectNombre[i] + "\n");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    System.out.println("Correos Enviados Correctamente\n");
    System.out.println("Total Correos Enviados: " + vect.length + "\n");
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Creo que la respuesta a tu pregunta sería: ***haciendo que no haya excepciones***. No le veo sentido a continuar ejecutando un código después de una `Excepción`. Por ejemplo, si la excepción es que no hay conexión de internet, o que no hay memoria, o que no puede seguir leyendo el archivo desde el cual saca los datos que hay que enviar... ¿cómo vas a seguir enviando si ha fallado algo necesario para continuar trabajando?

Comment: @A.Cedano Dependiendo del tipo de aplicación, que se detenga el trabajo por una excepción puede no ser una opción aceptable. Por ejemplo: si se están mandando 10.000 emails con ficheros adjuntos (diferentes para cada email) y por cualquier motivo no se encuentra uno de los ficheros lanzando una excepción, ¿debemos hacer que no se envíen los otros 9.999 (que son válidos) porque hubo un fallo en 1 de ellos? ¿O si el error de que no hay memoria se lanza porque un fichero es demasiado grande pero el resto no lo son?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yo sinceramente no levantaría simplemente una excepción y continuaría enviando los otros sin más, por una sencilla razón: **tener que verificar luego cuáles se enviaron y cuáles no podrían ser una tarea ardua** sobre todo si se trata de 10,000 o 100 mil o 1 millón de mensajes. No creo que esto se deba  manejar con excepciones, sino haciendo las verificaciones de lugar, que podrían provocar un fallo, **escribiendo en alguna parte los casos fallidos** (para saber los que no se enviaron) y enviando los que pasen la prueba.

Comment: @A.Cedano comprendo, pero es que las excepciones son... excepcionales, no se preveen, simplemente ocurren y pueden ocurrir por causas fuera del control del desarrollador y que no se pueden verificar. Comprobar después cuáles se enviaron y cuáles no, no tiene que ver con la excepción en sí y no tiene que ser una tarea ardua (dependerá de cómo se diseñe el programa).

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como lo tienes ahora (en *pseudo-código*, simplificado para legibilidad):

```
try {
  for (x = 0; x < numero_elementos; x++) {
    // realizar operaciones para mandar correo
  }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Si ocurre una excepción, ésta se atrapará fuera del bucle `for` por lo que el flujo del programa estará fuera del bucle y ya no se seguirán procesando el resto de correos.

Ahora, si mueves el `try...catch` de donde lo tienes a dentro del bucle en sí, si ocurre una excepción al enviar un correo, como el `catch` está dentro del bucle, se procesará el error y se continuará con el siguiente correo. Además, en lugar de dejar el `catch` vacío, podrías realizar alguna operación (p.e. guardar el ID del correo que fallo o algo que lo identifique para que pueda ser reprocesado más adelante):

```
for (x = 0; x < numero_elementos; x++) {
  try {
    // realizar operaciones para mandar correo
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // realizar operaciones después de excepción
  }
}
```

Incluso podrías tener 2 estructuras `try...catch` una fuera del bucle y otra dentro de él. De ese modo, el `try...catch` interno procesará errores individuales y podría tener algo de lógica para lanzar una excepción al `try...catch` externo (p.e. si la excepción no se va a poder recuperar y no se debe continuar con el resto de emails).